# Мое приложение устанавливается на телефон, но не запускается

Tags: java, android

Написал приложение, которое работает с сетью и данными о местоположении.

Установил на свой девайс - всё ок. Приложение установилось, и всё нормально работает. Прошивка у меня 6, проверял и на 5-м, и на 4-м. Думаю, версия об прошивке отпадает. Но на некоторые телефоны оно устанавливается, но не запускается!

Как быть? Пишет *"приложение остановлено"*, но в логах нету ничего об ошибках.

Comment: Покажите логи. На некоторых устройствах, например, на некоторых моделях Huawei, они по-умолчанию отключены.

Comment: Думаю если добавите модели телефонов на которых останавливается - будет больше шансов найти товарищей по несчастью кто с таким сталкивался.

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо Тем кто хоть как то отреагировал.Модели телефонов на которых тестировал(реальные девайсы):

Samsung : S классы

Lenovo

Huawei

Htc

На 2 устройствах одинаковой прошивки реагировал по разному.На одном открывал на другом нет.

После того как откладка не помагла найти ошибку почитал и нашел схожую ситуацию.
Дело в multidex

1)добавил в   gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

2)прописал там же :

```
android {
     defaultConfig {

 multiDexEnabled true
    }
....
```

3)Добавил в манифест

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
</application>
```

У меня и до этого были сделаны первые 2 шага .После того как добавил  3 всё заработало .Надеюсь комуто поможет !